# How to create a separate table for the user when they register on a site

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have to create a site where every user stores their data, and each user gets the isolated storage for which I have to allot a particular table to each user, so the size for the data stored by user is big enough too. I don't know how to do this in Django. Please suggest a way to do this.

Comment: Read about multi tenant applications with django. http://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-multi-tenant/en/latest/

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, after reading  the content of  book i really think this will help me out.